# How to import dependecies from build.gradle to pom.xml

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml, maven-publish

I use `maven-publish` plugin for deploying android library(`.aar`).

My library has another dependencies, which are also `.aar`

How can I import all dependencies from `build.gradle`, `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'

    //Http communication, websockets, etc.
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

    //Fonts
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'

    //Unit tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'

    //Other
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    //Reactive programmnig
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}
```

To generated `pom.xml` `dependencies` section:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>SDK</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>aar</packaging>

<dependencies>
   ...
</dependencies>

</project>
```

I found some explanation how to do similar things:

[Optional Gradle dependencies for Maven libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345804/optional-gradle-dependencies-for-maven-libraries)

[How to change artifactory runtime scope to compile scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069666/how-to-change-artifactory-runtime-scope-to-compile-scope)

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1749

http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/6ac07fb41846/how-to-maven-publish-a-gradle-project-jar-with-provided-scope.html

So, I understood, that I should use `pom.withXml`, import all dependecies from `project.configurations.compile.allDependencies` with scope `compile`, and put it into `asNode().dependencies`

But I'm not familiar with it, and I think I doing something wrong. Here is my current code:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact "${project.buildDir}/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar"
            artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            groupId = GROUP
            version = VERSION_NAME

            // Task androidSourcesJar is provided by gradle-mvn-push.gradle
            //artifact androidSourcesJar {
            //    classifier "sources"
            //}

            pom.withXml {
                def depsNode = asNode().dependencies.'*'
                project.configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { dep ->
                    if(dep.name != null && dep.group != null && dep.version != null) {
                        def depNode = new Node(null, 'dependency')

                        def groupIdNode = new Node(depNode, 'groupId', dep.getGroup())
                        def artifactIdNode = new Node(depNode, 'artifactId', dep.getName())
                        def versionNode = new Node(depNode, 'version', dep.getVersion())


                        depsNode.add(depNode)
                        println depsNode
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv('NEXUS_USER_NAME')
                password System.getenv('NEXUS_PASSWORD')
            }
            url "http://nexus-repo"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use `pom.withXml` to modify the generated pom.xml, but you shouldn't have to do any custom config to include all runtime dependencies (which by default also includes compile dependencies.) What is the problem you're running into?

Comment: @RaGe, problem is that generated `pom.xml` has no any dependencies. But I want it to have all dependencies with `compile` scope

Comment: @RaGe, when I built my `.aar` dependency and include it in another app, I need include all dependecies from my library project, because I always get `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: My comment above is for a gradle java project in general - just tried it and the `compile` dependencies are written properly in the pom.xml file. I suppose your situation is different because it is an android project - looking around I found a plugin specifically for publishing .aar files in an android plugin - posting below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To publish a `.aar` library with the dependencies listed correctly in pom.xml, it might be easier to use [this](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) plugin, rather than assemble the dependencies section yourself using the maven-publish plugin.

To apply plugin:

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "1.3"
}
```

and run task `install` to push library to local .m2 repo.

You can override the repo being published to like this:

```
install {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(...)
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can of course, continue to use the `maven-publish` plugin if you so prefer. In your code, you're looking for `depsNode` which does not already exist. You likely need to create a new Node for depsNode and add it to the pom first. Or just use append:

```
pom.withXml {
    def depsNode  = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

    configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {  dep ->
        def depNode  = depsNode.appendNode('dependency')
        depNode.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
        depNode.appendNode('artifactId', dep.name)
        depNode.appendNode('version', dep.version)
        //optional add scope
        //optional add transitive exclusions
    }
}
```

The caveat here is that, you still need to handle exclusions correctly. Also, if you have variants in your project, and have different compile configurations such as `androidCompile` or `somethingElseCompile`, you need to handle those correctly as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it today later and I'll appreciate it if it will help me.

Comment: I didn't test first part, because second part works for me

Comment: For gradle maven plugin version 1.4.1, use this    **configurations.releaseCompileClasspath.allDependencies.each** to write all dependencies in **pom.xml**

Answer (score 1):

You can update the dependencies with the dependencies of another project or library in the maven publish task. This has to be done before jar generation task. In this way, the changes will be reflected in the pom generation and no need for pom xml manipulation. getDependencies is the method that you extract those dependencies and you should implement it ;)

This is the snippet in the publish task

```
        artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
        groupId = GROUP
        version = VERSION_NAME

        project.configurations.implementation.withDependencies { dependencies ->            
             dependencies.addAll(getDependencies(project)) 
        }

        from components.java
```